# Doctrine: How to suppress further lifecycle events when updating entities inside entity's listener?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I am working on an app in Symfony 3 using Doctrine.

Whenever I persist or update a specific entity, I need to query for a subset of these entities (same class) and update a property for each.

Currently I have an entity listener class with postPersist() and postUpdate() handlers which call a function performing the aforementioned behaviour.

However, I am finding that when persisting changes for these other entities, it is triggering events leading to additional lifecycle callbacks to postUpdate() on the same listener (as somewhat expected, but undesired).

I wanted to ask if anyone would know of a way to suppress these additional events or possibly have any ideas on alternative solutions to this scenario.

**Update**: Providing sample code to help illustrate the issue

```
// Subscribed Entity Listener for Foo
class FooListener
{

  ...

  public function postPersist(Foo $foo, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
  {
    ...

    $this->updateFlaggedFoos($event);
  }

  public function postUpdate(Foo $foo, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
  {
    ...

    $this->updateFlaggedFoos($event);
  }

  private function updateFlaggedFoos(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
  {
    $user          = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    $entityManager = $event->getEntityManager();
    $userFoos      = $entityManager->getRepository('MyApp:Foo')->getUserFoos($user);

    foreach($userFoos as $foo) {
      if ($this->determineIfFlagValueNeedsToChange($foo)) {
        $foo->setFlagValue( ! $foo->isFlagged());
        $entityManager->persist($foo);   // Causes postUpdate() to be called again.
      }
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the listener code (relevant parts only)?

Comment: Updated question with sample code

Comment: Is there a particular reason you’re using post* events? Could you use pre* events instead?

Comment: @lxg is right, unless there is no good reason do it in pre* events, this includes as well a rollback (e.g. when a postUpdate change fails you'd still have the first flush in your database) - so gather all changes before flushing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, just to clarify, so if logic is moved to pre* events, unlike in postUpdate(), it should avoid further calls to preUpdate() for the other updated items?